# In which directory i should keep my workspace or project

Tags: php

I have installed XAMPP in my machine(Windows XP OS). And I have Eclipse as IDE.
Now my question is, In which directory i should keep my workspace (or project).
Whether I should keep under  the path "C:\xampp\php\www" OR under "C:\xampp\htdocs".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to change the DocumentRoot value in c:\xampp\apache\conf\httpd.conf from

```
DocumentRoot "C:\xampp\htdocs"
```

to

```
DocumentRoot "E:/MyProject/Source/Admin"
```

and configure permissions also.

```
<Directory "E:/MyProject/Source/Admin">
        Options +Indexes FollowSymLinks +ExecCGI
        AllowOverride AuthConfig FileInfo
        Order allow,deny
        Allow from all
</Directory>
```

and then restart the apache server(in xampp control panel). so from there onwards whenever you access http://localhost/ it will execute the files under E:/MyProject/Source/Admin

see for more info.
http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/mod/core.html#documentroot 
http://www.apachefriends.org/en/xampp-windows.html#529

Comment: ok.. But How can I configure in httpd.conf. Could you explain me clearly please

Comment: Yes mahesh I have change the path of DocumentRoot to "E:/MyProject/Source/Admin". And restarted the Apache also but its throwing the error as.......... Access forbidden!

You don't have permission to access the requested directory. There is either no index document or the directory is read-protected.

If you think this is a server error, please contact the webmaster.

Comment: is there any index.php or index.html there on E:/MyProject/Source/Admin?

Comment: No I haven't change the configuring permissions. where exactly and what to change....

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the [**Where I change the start page?**](http://www.apachefriends.org/en/faq-xampp-windows.html#startpage) section of XAMP's FAQ *(quoting)* :

> The `DocumentRoot` folder is
>   `"\xampp\htdocs"`. 
> There is the
>   index site (`index.php`) the real
>   start page which is loaded after
>   executing of `"http://localhost/"`.

So, I'd say, in your case, you'll have to work in `C:\xampp\htdocs`.

Still, of course, you can change that by modifying Apache's configuration and/or creating new VirtualHosts.

Comment: How to create the VirtualHosts.